# Matlab: command to check for zero sparse matrix?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I need a command to check for zero sparse matrix, isempty(..) does not work. Is there some sparse version of isempty(..)?

```
>> mlf2=sparse([],[],[],2^31+1,1)

mlf2 =

   All zero sparse: 2147483649-by-1

>> isempty(mlf2)

ans =

     0       % I waited for 1 here with the zero sparse matrix...
```

Comment: note that it is not a sparseness issue. `isempty(0)` will also evaluate as `false`  as zero is not empty. Normally you can use `any` or `nnz` to determine whether there are nonzeros.

Comment: `nnz`, `nonzeros`, `nzmax`, etc. are all in the See Also section of the [`sparse` doc page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html).  There are several useful companion functions.  Worth a look IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
~nnz(mlf2)
```

or

```
isempty(find(mlf2))
```

**Edit:**

Mohsen Nosratinia pointed out that `isempty(find(mlf2), 1)` is more efficient because it the `find` command will either return a matrix of length 1, or an empty matrix

Comment: +1 for a nice answer. For second solution, `isempty(find(mlf2,1))` seems to be more efficient.